# Error when uploading new iPad app version: "iPad: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): i386"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm trying to update my iPad app on the App Store. I filled out the "new version" form on iTunes Connect and then tried to upload the new version with Application Loader. It rejected the .zip file giving me three errors.

---

I had changed the "Bundle Version" line in the Info.plist file to 1.1, and added "Bundle versions string, short" (also 1.1). Then I build the .app file, and zipped it up with the .mobileprovision file.

**The zip file:** Chordpad.zip
**Contains:** ChordPad.app, ChordPad_Distribution.mobileprovision

**These are the errors Application Loader is giving me:**
1. iPad: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): i386
2. Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate.
3. Unable to extract codesigning entitlements from your application. Please make sure ChordPad.app is  a valid Mach executable that's properly codesigned.

As far as I know, all my certificates are valid. Could anyone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the i386 architecture is being used, you are probably building for the simulator. Switch to device to get the arm architectures.